# PrimeNG ConfirmationService does not wait for an answer

Tags: angular, promise, observable, primeng

I have a parent component with the following function:

```
@ViewChild('currentTab') currentTab: ChildComponent;  
  
nextTab(): void {
  if (this.currentTab.save()) {
    this.activeIndex++; 
  }
}
```

And the following method on the child component:

```
save(): boolean {
  return this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure?',
    accept: () => true,
    reject: () => false
  });
}
```

The problem: The conditional in the parent component doesn't wait for an answer, it gets as 'true', doing the `this.activeIndex++;` . What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript** is always **synchronous** and **single-threaded**. So the expression `this.currentTab.save()` is resolved and `if(....)` statement is evaluated immediately.As per [PrimeNg source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/api/confirmationservice.ts) the `confirm(...)` method fire a signal to display the popup dialog then return `this` which is a truthy value. So It is expected that `activeIndex` always increase.

To achive what you want, import and use the confirm service in the parent component :

```
nextTab(): void {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
     message: 'Are you sure?',
     accept: () => this.activeIndex++,
     reject: () => //Do something else
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well this also not working and nit returning anything

Comment: Yes, the point is the  `this.confirmationService.confirm` method is working as handler, not for returning any value

Comment: well here the answer for this issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65239651/how-to-get-the-confirmation-service-of-primeng-wait-for-the-approval-or-denial-o

Comment: Well then is it working as handler and not for returning value?